# Tastypie Dehydrate reverse relation count

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a simple model which includes a product and category table. The Product model has a foreign key Category.

When I make a tastypie API call that returns a list of categories /api/vi/categories/
I would like to add a field that determines the "product count" / the number of products that have a giving category. The result would be something like:

```
category_objects[
{ 
   id: 53
   name: Laptops
   product_count: 7
}, 
...
 ]
```

The following code is working but the hit on my DB is heavy

```
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        category = Category.objects.get(pk=bundle.obj.id)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
        bundle.data['product_count'] = products.count()
        return bundle
```

Is there a more efficient way to build this query? Perhaps with annotate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does additional count query for each category. You're right about `annotate` being helpfull in this kind of a problem.

Django will include all queryset's fields in `GROUP BY` statement. Notice `.values()` and empty `.group_by()` serve limiting field set to required fields.

```
cat_to_prod_count = dict(Product.objects
                                .values('category_id')
                                .order_by()
                                .annotate(product_count=Count('id'))
                                .values_list('category_id', 'product_count'))
```

The above `dict` object is a map [category_id -> product_count].

It can be used in `dehydrate` method:

```
 bundle.data['product_count'] = cat_to_prod_count[bundle.obj.id]
```

If that doesn't help, try to keep similar counter on category records and use singals to keep it up to date.

Note categories are usually a tree-like beings and you probably want to keep count of all subcategories as well.

In that case look at the package [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/).

Comment: This solution decreased the query time by half of what it was. I did have to add a Try Except in my code to handle if there was 0/no product relationship

Answer (score 4):

You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method of `QuerSet` to reverse select_related.

Asper documentation,

> #### prefetch_related(*lookups)
>
> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically
>   retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified
>   lookups.
>
> This has a similar purpose to select_related, in that both are
>   designed to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by
>   accessing related objects, but the strategy is quite different.

If you change your dehydrate function to following then database will be hit single time.

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    category = Category.objects.prefetch_related("product_set").get(pk=bundle.obj.id)
    bundle.data['product_count'] = category.product_set.count()
    return bundle
```

### UPDATE 1

You should not initialize queryset inside dehydrate function. queryset should be always set in `Meta` class only. Please have a look at following example from `django-tastypie` documentation.

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        # If they're requesting their own record, add in their email address.
        if bundle.request.user.pk == bundle.obj.pk:
            # Note that there isn't an ``email`` field on the ``Resource``.
            # By this time, it doesn't matter, as the built data will no
            # longer be checked against the fields on the ``Resource``.
            bundle.data['email'] = bundle.obj.email

        return bundle
```

As per official `django-tastypie` [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#dehydrate) on `dehydrate()` function,

> **dehydrate**
>
> The dehydrate method takes a now fully-populated bundle.data & make
>   any last alterations to it. This is useful for when a piece of data
>   might depend on more than one field, if you want to shove in extra
>   data that isn’t worth having its own field or if you want to
>   dynamically remove things from the data to be returned.

`dehydrate()` is only meant to make any last alterations to bundle.data.

Comment: This is not true. The `.count()` call does single db query. The problem is `dehydrate` function is called for each category. Your code actually does two queries. One for `prefetch_related` and another for `.count()` call which doesn't use previous db query at all. Instead it performs separate `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... ` query.

Comment: Thank you - after diving into tastypie docs I should set the queryset outside of dehydrate